# How can I create a completely un-styled list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

So I want to create a list view in SwiftUI where each cell *only* displays the contents of the views inside of it.  I.e. there is no background color, and there are no lines dividing the cells.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Use `ScrollView` and `ForEach` rather than `List`

Comment: Can I use swipe controls with scrollview, or will I need to re-implement that?

Comment: You’d have to reimplement